# Using two different dice, what is the probability of one being greater/smaller/same?

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose A and B play game and use dice with 1...A and 1...B values, respectively - who tosses more, wins.

What is the chance that A wins, B wins or the game is tie, based on the values?

A few years ago, I have made a grid for exact values A/B and got the results, but I would appreciate more "advanced" solution, or at least hints.

Additionally: How would the solution change if I chose different minimum and maximum values (rather than one dice being a superset of the other), but the intersection of intervals would contain the same values (e.g. 1...6 and 3...10, but not 1,3,5 and 2,3,4)? Or, if the probability space was infinite (e.g. any rational number from given intervals can be rolled), what would change?

Edit: My attempt on solution (I hope succesful):

Let's say A has the smaller values (set A), where B has the bigger values (set B). Place the values on a line, and let be:

x - size of left area (|A-B|)

y - size of intersecting area (|A intersection B|)

z - size of right area (|B-A|)

n - total amount of different values (x+y+z, |A union B|)

I will also explicitly provide the solution if the value rolls into either exclusively left or right area, but will not sum the probabilities, just subtract "A wins" and "Tie" from 1, in order to get chance "B wins".

---

Left area:
A has a chance x/n to get his value there. B always wins.

---

Right area:
B has a chance z/n to get his value there, and wins regardless of where A gets the roll. But the left area was already counted, so the chance in this case is (y/n)*(z/n) for B.

---

Middle area:

Chance for A to get into the middle area is y/(x+y), and for B is y/(y+z), together:

y^2/((x+y)(y+z))

In this case, the probability for win/loss is the same. But first, let's have a look at tie, which has chance 1/y (A can get anywhere, B must match). That's exactly y/((x+y)(y+z)).

To get the win chance, one subtracts the tie chance and divides the remainder by 2. That gives:

y(y-1)/(2(x+y)(y+z)) chance for A to win (at all).

---

Chance to win for player A:

```
y(y-1)/(2(x+y)(y+z))
```

Chance to tie:

`y/((x+y)(y+z))`

Chance to win for player B:

`1-(y(y+1))/(2(x+y)(y+z))`

This ended up being harder than I first thought - it was easier when x=0 :)

---

Infinity solution:

If we used computer to evenly generate any number from given interval and increased the precision, the ratio between x,y and z would not change at all. Therefore, the only thing that would change (again, intuitively) is the tie - it's less probable that two same numbers on the same interval are generated, the lower the gap between numbers is.

Comment: "*if the probability space was infinite (e.g. any rational number from given intervals can be rolled)*" There is no such thing as a uniform distribution on a countably infinite set so it is impossible to even imagine such a scenario with rational numbers.  You *could* have a uniform distribution on an *uncountably* infinite set, e.g. the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ picking any *real* number in that interval... (*answering that question is practically a geometry problem*) but not a countably infinite one.

Comment: As for how to approach the general (*finite*) problem where the first player rolls numbers from $\{a,a+1,a+2,a+3,\dots,A\}$ and the second player rolls numbers from $\{b,b+1,b+2,b+3,\dots,B\}$ where their intersection is of size $n$... you should be able to see that if both dice results are in the intersection, there are $n$ ways in which case they tie, or otherwise the same number of ways for first player to win versus the second player to win.  All others are such that if one player rolls a number smaller than the intersection they certainly lose and larger they certainly win. Formalize this

Comment: @JMoravitz

Yeah infinite probability spaces are pretty weird, discrete maths teacher told us to stay away from them. 
So if I decided that the dice have better "precision" as for 0.1, 0.01..., I could enlarge the probability space to 6->60->600... and 8->80->800
and for that calculate limit. But only on real numbers, if I understand correctly?